# distance between two locations is not right?

Tags: android, location, distance

i get two locations using this :

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

then i compute the distance between them , but the distance is not true

```
public static float calculateDistance(double e, double f, double g, double h)
{
    float dLat = (float) Math.toRadians(g - e);
    float dLon = (float) Math.toRadians(h - f);
    float a =
            (float) (Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(e))
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(g)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2));
    float c = (float) (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)));
    float d = 6371 * c;
    return d;
}
```

(32.2163799,35.0420986)
(31.9210915,35.2037014)

the result 36.193707 km 
but the actual is more than that , approximately 85 km

Comment: how do you know that the diszance is not true? where you got the 85km from? have you checked the distance with a web page allowing distance calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standart function for this:

```
Location location1 = new Location("<provider name");
location1.setLatitude(lat1);
location1.setLongitude(lng1);

Location location2 = new Location("<provider name");
location2.setLatitude(lat2);
location2.setLongitude(lng2);

float distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

More info:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29

Or distance between function:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29

Answer (score 0):

Use static method [distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) to get distance in meters

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0]
```

Note that the results array packs together several values relating to the distance between the two points:

```
  - results[0] -  distance in meters
  - results[1] -  initial bearing angle of the shortest path between them
  - results[2] -  final bearing angle of the shortest path between them
```