# convert getLastLocation() result into separate latitude and longitude

Tags: android, geolocation

I successfully retrieved the last location. I found many answers on SO about calculating the difference in distance between two points, but they seem to have their latitude and longitude separated?

My result is this(numbers changed for example):

```
Location[fused 12.345678,-123.456789 acc=30 et=+19h26m17s811ms]
```

How do I separate the latitude and longitude for use like this:

```
float[] results = new float[3];
Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0]
```

I found this code on this stack overflow question: [distance between two locations is not right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714204/distance-between-two-locations-is-not-right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) has 2 methods to calculate the distance to another Location:

- `static void distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)`which writes the distance to the results array
- `float distanceTo(Location dest)` which returns the distance as a float.

So you can either call distanceTo on your Location-object, or you can call `Location.distanceBetween` and pass in the 2 Latitude/Longitude pairs.